# Get the count of an array where values are similar in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array:

```
[
class: [
        0: "538c5cd9dda3aae409000038",
        1: "538c5cd9dda3aae409000037"
        ],
section: [
          0: "O",
          1: "N"
          ],
religion: "",
gender: "",
nationality: "",
bloodgroup: "",
quota: "",
shorting: "rollno",
fieldstudentname: "on",
fieldrollno: "on",
fieldreligion: "on",
fieldaddress: "on",
fieldgender: "on",
fieldaadhar: "on",
fieldcategory: "on",
classbulklist: "Search"
]
```

Now, I want the count only with values "on". In above example the count will be 7. How to achieve this without for, foreach loop.

Comment: `array_count_values`

Comment: Before posting it here, please try to solve it first

Comment: @pinoyCoder I already tried with loops but I want it without loops....

Comment: @iainn while trying array_count_values then its giving following error: Warning: array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER values!

Comment: Your array is invalid PHP syntax. Seems you posted JSON encoded version of it? Do you have a JSON string like this or do you have a true array?

Comment: @trincot I have an array in php..Firstly I have given an idea.. You can check now..I have edited it..

Comment: This still is not valid PHP syntax. In PHP key/value pairs are written as `"key" => value`, not `key: value`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` to filter-out the non-matching values, and then count the result.

```
$callback = function($value) {
    return ($value === "on");
};

$count = count(array_filter($your_array, $callback));
```

A similar callback could also be used as a counter callback with `array_walk()` (though, `array_filter()` would also work), but this really wouldn't be any different than using a regular loop.

Answer (score 0):

As you specified your array in non-PHP syntax (but more like JavaScript syntax), I will assume your array is like this:

```
$data = [
    (object) [
        "class" => (object) [
            0 => "538c5cd9dda3aae409000038",
            1 => "538c5cd9dda3aae409000037"
        ],
        "section" => (object) [
            0 => "O",
            1 => "N"
        ],
        "religion" => "",
        "gender" => "",
        "nationality" => "",
        "bloodgroup" => "",
        "quota" => "",
        "shorting" => "rollno",
        "fieldstudentname" => "on",
        "fieldrollno" => "on",
        "fieldreligion" => "on",
        "fieldaddress" => "on",
        "fieldgender" => "on",
        "fieldaadhar" => "on",
        "fieldcategory" => "on",
        "classbulklist" => "Search"
    ]
];
```

In that case, you need to first get the first element of the array (it only has one element), then get that object as an associative array with `get_object_vars`, then apply filter on its values, and finally take the count of the resulting array:

```
$count = count(array_filter(get_object_vars($data[0]), function ($val) {
    return $val === "on";
}));
```

#### After your edit

... it seems you don't have objects, but only nested arrays. In that case you should omit the call to `get_object_vars`:

```
$count = count(array_filter($data[0], function ($val) {
    return $val === "on";
}));
```